# How to make git aws.push verbose

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When I used to use `git aws.push`, I used to see some logs live, with some kind of percentage showing progress.

Now I have a new computer, and re-installed all the tools.

However, `git aws.push` now just shows:

```
Nathans-MacBook-Pro:MyProject nathanh$ git aws.push
Updating the AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment Production...
Environment update initiated successfully.
```

With a long pause between line 2 and 3. No progress, nothing...

How can I get back those status messages?

Comment: looking at the code that's being run upon aws.push I see no reference of any log printing but the ones you listed. maybe this changed over time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using EB CLI 3.x http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-getting-set-up.html,

you can run `eb deploy <your_environment>`

if you want more details, you can also use the `--verbose` option: `eb deploy <your_environment> --verbose`

If you think you have issue with your Elactic Beanstalk settings, you can reset and restart the configuration from scratch, removing the folders `.elasticbeanstalk/` from your application folder and your user folder (`~/.elasticbeanstalk/`). Then run `eb init` from your application folder.

Comment: I've tried that already. If I try to deploy it says I have no environment. You can't do anything unless you do the init, which will create a NEW application configuration.

Comment: It should prompt for you to select your application when you run `eb init`. In my case I had: `$ eb init

Select an application to use
1) app1
2) app2
3) [ Create new Application ]
(default is 3): `

Comment: I'd love to know how you achieve this! In my case it immediately said "application Xx was created". No questions asked.

Comment: Maybe I can reset my AWS configuration? Do you know how to do that?

Comment: remove the folder `.elasticbeanstalk/` (`eb init` will recreate it)

Comment: No I've tried that, same thing. I mean reset the global configuration (it didn't ask for my AWS account for example)

Comment: this configuration files are in your user folder : `~/.elasticbeanstalk/`

Comment: Yes that fixed it! Deleted this folder and did it all from scratch, it found my application. Update your answer with all the relevant information so I can accept it.

Comment: One disappointing thing about this new EB: the old one used to only upload the incremental update (thanks to git). The new one seems to generate a zip file and upload the whole thing.

Comment: you're right, that's not cool. Thread on AWS forum: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=164847

Answer (score 1):

You should switch to the new EB CLI 3.0.  Git aws.push will soon be deprecated. 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-getting-started.html

Full reference is available at : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-cmd-commands.html

Comment: I'm trying to play with it. I can't understand how to load an existing application. Everything has to start with `eb init` which creates a new application.

Comment: eb init creates an application definition on Elastic Beanstalk.  It does not create your application - just an application definition in the cloud.  So, starting with an existing code, git init, eb init, eb create dev, eb deploy and you should be ready !

Comment: Right, but I already have an application definition in the cloud, and a live environment! My point is there is no way to connect my code to an existing application, just create a new one.